# BigQuery Script for Getting Average Days of Specific Date Period

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to build a query **for days on market (DOM) for Jan 2021 = AVG(sold date - contract date) for all properties that sold date is [20210101 =< Sold Date =< 20210131]**

This is  what I have written:

```
SELECT AVG(DATE_DIFF(field_3102,field_3103)) as DOM 
   FROM `winter-agility-327715.Properties_dataset.Final_Table` 
WHERE field_3102 BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31'
```

`field_3102` is basically sold date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall logic on your written query already matches the above requirement. However, it will not run because of a syntax error using `DATE_DIFF()` function. To correct this, you must specify a `date_part` on your `DATE_DIFF()` function. You may refer to this [BigQuery - DATE_DIFF Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_diff) for more details.

See below updated query.

```
SELECT AVG(DATE_DIFF(field_3102,field_3103,DAY)) as DOM 
   FROM `winter-agility-327715.Properties_dataset.Final_Table` 
WHERE field_3102 BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31'
```

Since your query requirement is **DAYS on market**, we used the `date_part` *"DAY"* for us to return the intervals in *DAYS*.